# Why this jquery code is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

**Html markup**

```
<div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="button" class="adddate">Add Date</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <div class="datesaccordion panel-group">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="button" class="adddate">Add Date</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <div class="datesaccordion panel-group">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="button" class="adddate">Add Date</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <div class="datesaccordion panel-group">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".adddate", addDate);    
function addDate(e) {
    $(e.target).closest(".datesaccordion").append($("<p />").html("test"));
}
```

Here i am trying to insert the DHTML on *.adddate* button click. And i want to inter the DHTML in the closest *.datesaccordion* div from *.adddate* button. But the jquery code
*(above mentioned)* is not working.

Can anybody please tell me what i am missing??

Comment: `e.target` should just be `this`, and `.datesaccordion` isn't an ancestor of the button, so of course it won't be picked up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
$(document).on("click", ".adddate", addDate);
function addDate(e) {
    $(this).parent().next().find(".datesaccordion").append($("<p />").html("test"));
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sLaWZ/)

The `datesaccordion` element is not a ancestor of the button, it is a descdendant of the next sibling of the buttons's parent, so you cannot use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) here

Comment: What's `<p />`? Is that valid?

Comment: @Mr.Alien it is adding a new `p` element to the `datesaccordion` element. The `$("<p />")` syntax creates a new `p` element instead of doing a dom lookup

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).on("click", ".adddate", addDate);
```

instead of:

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".adddate", addDate);
```

as well as changing your `addDate()` function to this:

```
function addDate(e) {
    $(this).parent().siblings('.col-md-12').find('.datesaccordion').append($("<p />").html("test"));
}
```